# Adding a "if" "then" checkbutton

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, calculator

I am new to coding and I wrote some code for a calculator I use to solve some stuff at work.

I am now stuck trying to add check buttons for "feet" & "meters". I want them to integrate into my equation, that way I wont have to convert them manually beforehand. I will add the second equation for feet once I can figure out how to make them toggle between the two.

Here is my code so far:

```
import Tkinter
import math
from Tkinter import *


Lreq = 105
Dref = 1

class compintapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self["bg"] = "grey"


        ## Title & subtitle labels ---------------------------------------
        titlelbl = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Wattage Calculator",
                              anchor="center",fg="black",bg="darkorange2")
        titlelbl.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4,sticky='EW')




        ## Input Labels --------------------------------------------------

        sensitivitylbl = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Loudspeaker sensitivity?",
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="SlateGray4")
        sensitivitylbl.grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=3,sticky='EW')

        distancelbl = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Distance from speaker to listening position?",
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="SlateGray4")
        distancelbl.grid(column=0,row=3,columnspan=3,sticky='EW')

        headroomlbl = Tkinter.Label(self, text="How much headroom for amplifier?",
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="SlateGray4")
        headroomlbl.grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=3,sticky='EW')


        wattagelbl = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Total Wattage :",
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="SlateGray4")
        wattagelbl.grid(column=0,row=7,columnspan=3,sticky='EW')



        ## end of input labels ------------------------------------------------

        ## Input Boxes --------------------------------------------------------
        #self.sensitivity = Tkinter.DoubleVar()
        #speakersensitivity = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.sensitivity)
        #speakersensitivity.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='EW')

        self.sensitivity = Tkinter.DoubleVar()
        speakersensitivity = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.sensitivity)
        speakersensitivity.grid(column=3,row=2,sticky='EW')

        self.distance = Tkinter.DoubleVar()
        spkdistance = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.distance)
        spkdistance.grid(column=3,row=3,sticky='EW')

        self.headroom = Tkinter.IntVar()
        spkheadroom = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.headroom)
        spkheadroom.grid(column=3,row=4, sticky='EW')


        ## end of input boxes -------------------------------------------------

        ## Button
        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="C A L C U L A T E",
                                anchor="w",fg="black",bg="green",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=0,row=6,columnspan=1)




        var = BooleanVar()

        c=Checkbutton(self, text="Meters", variable=BooleanVar(),
                      anchor="center",fg="white",bg="grey25")
        c.grid(column=2,row=6,columnspan=1)

        c=Checkbutton(self, text="Feet", variable=BooleanVar(),
                      anchor="center",fg="white",bg="grey25")
        c.grid(column=3,row=6,columnspan=1)




        # initialize global variables
        self.ckbuttonstatus = BooleanVar()



        ## end of button

        ## Output labels
        self.amt = Tkinter.StringVar()
        amtout = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.amt,
                              anchor="e",fg="red",bg="gold")
        amtout.grid(column=3,row=7,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')

        ## end of output labels -----------------------------------------------

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=2)
        self.resizable(0,0)


    def OnButtonClick(self):
        Lsens = self.sensitivity.get()
        D2 = self.distance.get()
        HR = self.headroom.get()


        exponent = (Lreq-Lsens+20 * math.log10(D2/1)+HR)/10
        amount = 10 ** exponent
        self.amt.set(amount)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = compintapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Wattage Calculator')
    app.mainloop()
```

I hope you all can help because I am having a really hard time finding anything on this.

Comment: What exactly _is_ the question?

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code

Comment: using `variable=BooleanVar()` inside `Checkbutton` has no sense because you don't have access to this `BooleanVar()` . You have to create `self.var = BooleanVar()` and use `variable=self.var` in `Checkbutton` and then you have access to `self.var` and you see if checkbutton was selected

Comment: So to be more specific, I want to be able to toggle between feet and meters when solving my equation. How would I put check boxes in there and allow them to control which equation to use to get my answer?

Comment: Furas, I will go ahead and try those suggestions and see if I can get the ball rolling with it. Thank you

Comment: you could use `Radiobuttons` instead of `Checkbuttons` and they will toggle one another.

Comment: Would Radiobuttons be an easier solution to this?

Comment: yes because when you select `meters` then you don't have unselect 'feet' - it will do it automatically

Comment: Okay great! Thank you. I will go ahead and work on this and I'll post once completed. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Radiobutton to select only one option `meters` or `feet`

You use one `IntVar` with two `Radiobutton` which have different `value`

```
self.option = tk.IntVar(value=1)

c = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Meters", value=1, variable=self.option)

c = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Feet", value=2, variable=self.option)
```

And in `OnButtonClick` you can get selected element (value `1` or `2) with

```
selected = self.option.get()

if selected == 1:
    print('meters')
else:
    print('feet')
```

---

**BTW:** you should use `try/except` because sometimes `log()` has wrong argument and give error.

**BTW:** we use `CamelCaseNames` for classes like `Label` or `Entry`. For other elements we use `lower_case_names` - for example `on_button_click`

---

Full code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import math

Lreq = 105
Dref = 1

class CompintAppTk(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Wattage Calculator')
        self.initialize()
        self.mainloop()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self["bg"] = "grey"

        ## Title & subtitle labels ---------------------------------------
        titlelbl = tk.Label(self, text="Wattage Calculator",
                              anchor="center", fg="black", bg="darkorange2")
        titlelbl.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky='EW')

        ## Input Labels --------------------------------------------------

        sensitivitylbl = tk.Label(self, text="Loudspeaker sensitivity?",
                              anchor="w", fg="white", bg="SlateGray4")
        sensitivitylbl.grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=3,sticky='EW')

        distancelbl = tk.Label(self, text="Distance from speaker to listening position?",
                              anchor="w", fg="white", bg="SlateGray4")
        distancelbl.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')

        headroomlbl = tk.Label(self, text="How much headroom for amplifier?",
                              anchor="w", fg="white", bg="SlateGray4")
        headroomlbl.grid(column=0,row=4, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')

        wattagelbl = tk.Label(self, text="Total Wattage :",
                              anchor="w", fg="white", bg="SlateGray4")
        wattagelbl.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')

        ## end of input labels ------------------------------------------------

        ## Input Boxes --------------------------------------------------------
        #self.sensitivity = tk.DoubleVar()
        #speakersensitivity = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.sensitivity)
        #speakersensitivity.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='EW')

        self.sensitivity = tk.DoubleVar()
        speakersensitivity = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.sensitivity)
        speakersensitivity.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky='EW')

        self.distance = tk.DoubleVar()
        spkdistance = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.distance)
        spkdistance.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky='EW')

        self.headroom = tk.IntVar()
        spkheadroom = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.headroom)
        spkheadroom.grid(column=3, row=4, sticky='EW')

        ## end of input boxes -------------------------------------------------

        ## Button
        button = tk.Button(self,text="C A L C U L A T E",
                                anchor="w", fg="black", bg="green",
                                command=self.on_button_click)
        button.grid(column=0, row=6)

        # initialize global variables
        self.option = tk.IntVar(value=1)

        c = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Meters", value=1, variable=self.option,
                      anchor="center", fg="grey25", bg="white")
        c.grid(column=2, row=6)

        c = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Feet", value=2, variable=self.option,
                      anchor="center", fg="grey25", bg="white")
        c.grid(column=3, row=6)

        ## end of button

        ## Output labels
        self.amt = tk.StringVar(self)
        amtout = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.amt,
                              anchor="e", fg="red", bg="gold")
        amtout.grid(column=3, row=7, sticky='EW')

        ## end of output labels -----------------------------------------------

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.resizable(0,0)


    def on_button_click(self):
        Lsens = self.sensitivity.get()
        D2 = self.distance.get()
        HR = self.headroom.get()

        selected = self.option.get()

        if selected == 1:
            print('meters')
        else:
            print('feet')

        try:    
            exponent = (Lreq-Lsens+20 * math.log10(D2/1)+HR)/10
            amount = 10 ** exponent
            self.amt.set(amount)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CompintAppTk()
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!